# How to disable URL and also Navigation Bar and Done button in only plain webbrowser?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

This is my screen and I want to handle it with my code. I don't want to show toolbar, done button or url. I create my own 'top', 'left' and 'back' buttons.

[image]

Below is my code

```
iabRef = window.open('http://', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

Please Help

Comment: i get my answer by my own.

Comment: Ans :- iabRef = window.open('http://XYZ'', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with inappbrowser options like

```
 var tabRef = window.open('www.testurl.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

Enjoy ;)